# javascript bootstrap-table initialized unwillingly

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-table

I am having problem with [bootstrap-table](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn), it automatically initializes and turn everything into the its style on `onload` or `onReady` event. But I want to use other table or just the standard table. It sometimes initializes all table on page but sometimes not. I can't find a solution on their document.

Do anybody know how it selects the table it wants to init by default?

Comment: Can you provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) ? It will be easier to help you this way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As stated in docs (see [usage](http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/getting-started/#usage)) bootstrap-tables are initialized in two ways:

- without writing JavaScript and setting `data-toggle="table"` attribute of `<table>` HTML element
- in Javascript calling `.bootstrapTable(options)` method on jQuery element (e.g `$('#table')`)

Other tables on a web page are not influenced.

Check this example on jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/beaver71/q5ctg2js/